# Assigning a selector passed to a method as a button target action

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

So here is my scenario. I'm making a toast view. The toast view accepts a selector which it sets as the target action of a button inside the toast view. But i get the unrecognised selector error.

```
 // MainViewController.swift

 func viewDidLoad() {

     // Custom initializer for toastview
     let toastView = ToastView(view: nil, selector: #selector(testSelector))
     .
     .
     .
 }

 @objc func testSelector() {
      print("Test")
 }

 // ToastView.swift

 var selector: Selector

 convenience init(view: UIView, selector: Selector) {
      self.selector = selector
      let button = UIButton(type: .system)
      button.addTarget(self, action: self.selector, for: .touchUpInside)
 }
```

Edit: Changed the code a bit to reflect what is actually in my original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the target wrong. Target must be an object of class where your selector (method or function) is defined. If function is defined in your `MainViewController` target must be an object of `MainViewController`. Same if function is defined in `ToastView` selector must be an object of `ToastView`.

Either you move your `testSelector` function in your `ToastView` class and keep rest the same.

**Option 1**

```
// something like this 
class ToastView {
    @objc func testSelector() {
        print("Test")
    } 
}
```

**Option 2**

Or you pass target as `init` paramater.

```
// ToastView.swift
convenience init(view: UIView, target:Any, selector: Selector) {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

And In your `MainViewController` call it like this.

```
func viewDidLoad() {

   // Custom initializer for toastview
   let toastView = ToastView(view: nil, target:self, selector: #selector(testSelector))
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: tried this. 
     button.addTarget(toast, selector: toast.selector, for: .touchUpInside)
Still getting the same issue.

Comment: How did you call it? Passing target as self?

Comment: No. Changed that to where the selector is kept. (Instance of ToastView)
Really sorry. Changed the question a bit to better reflect my actual use case.

Comment: Target has to be where your selector is defined. It defined in your viewcontriller so target shoud be self.

Comment: Passing both the target and selector to init is the better solution.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the delegate pattern, and make the button call something like `ToastViewDelegate.toastViewDidDismiss(_ toastView: ToastView)`

Comment: Ah i forgot that selector is passed as reference. My bad. Might have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You should move `testSelector` to your `ToastView` class if you want to perform the action in `ToastView` class.

If you want to perform the action in `MainViewController` then use a custom delegate.

Or declare `button` variable globally in `ToastView` class. Then you can add target in `MainViewController` using

```
let toastView = ToastView()
toastView.button.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
```

---

**OR**

You can use closure for the button action instead of selector

```
class ToastView: UIView {
    let button = UIButton()
    var btnAction:((Void) -> Void)?

    convenience init(_ btnAction: @escaping (Void) -> Void) {
        self.init()
        self.btnAction = btnAction
    }

    private init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callbackButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func callbackButton(_ id:Any) -> Void {
        if self.btnAction != nil {
            self.btnAction!()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**In MainViewController.swift**

```
func viewDidLoad() {

     // Custom initializer for toastview
     let toastView = ToastView.init( {(Void) -> Void in
        print("test")
    })
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont pass in the selector, instead no selector needs to be passed at all. 
Fire a Notification when the button is pressed and add an observer to the notification to the Controller. Do whatever action you want in that selector that is attached with the observer

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. But adding an observer adds overhead to such a tiny feature. Is there no way to pass a selector and get it to work ?

Comment: Why so? 
Passing a selector would infer passing different methods in the inittialisation of the toast, meaning different methods for different controller. Its basically the same over here.
Or you can also use a delegate for this, but passing selector from a controller to a view is basically calling for trouble.

Comment: Using notifications for button presses is almost never the solution.

Comment: As i said its an opinion, you can use delegates too, but IMO, using notifications for button action is a better solution than to pass selectors, or to the view itself.

Comment: Also, check if the deinit of the toast view gets called, if you do decide on passing on selector, as it might hold up some value and retain count might never reach 0

Comment: The only situation I can see that notifications would be a good solution is if the notification could potentially be handled by multiple view controllers.